# Issue with big Android App name

Tags: android

I want to publish my App on Play Store but my App name is big and it doesn't fit the App name area below the icon.

Actual App name: XYZ - ss:ssw:sw
Only need in phone: XYZ

I want my actual App name to be showed in Play Store and in settings but only XYZ everywhere else(On phone).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) when you try to add your app on market.. it asks application info which include "app name" too, here you can add FULL APP NAME, Which in terns will be app name on MARKET/PLAY_STORE.

2) change below string in res/values/String.xml file,

```
 <string name="app_name">app name to be displayed in phone</string>
```

which in terns set your application name in phone in application menu or you can say text below app icon.
hope it solves your problem..